# Give visitor access to password protected page/post via external script

Tags: login, password, remote-login

**Overview:**
On my site I want to do a customer area. There is a form where the visitor enters a name (e.g. "event_xyz") and a password. Only some well informed circles (participants of the event xyz who want to download some files) will know the access data.
By submitting, the visitor is redirected to a pp-redirect.php which should set the cookie to access the specific site the visitor wants to access - $_POST['name'] equals the post's slug.

I found this script to set that cookie and tried to solute my problem like this:

```
global $wp_hasher;
if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php' );
    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
}

setcookie( 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $wp_hasher->HashPassword( stripslashes( $_POST['pw'] ) ), 0, COOKIEPATH );

wp_safe_redirect( "http://www.domain.com/wordpress/".$_POST['name'] );
exit();
```

But this shows me the error that in this file and in wp-includes/pluggable.php the headers were already sent. I also don't know how the script, which is taken from the wp-login.php?action=postpass, knows which site I want to access.
Any solutions?

Comment: I assume that you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? That is how you are getting the errors? Do you have a live URL? Provide as much detail as you can, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution:

*form.php*

```
<form action="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/pp-redirect.php" method="post">
Event: <input name="event" type="text" size="25" /><br />
Passwort: <input name="post_password" type="password" size="25" /><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Los" />
</form>
```

*pp-redirect.php*

```
<?php
/** Make sure that the WordPress bootstrap has run before continuing. */
require( dirname(__FILE__) . './../../../wp-load.php');
global $wp_hasher;
if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php' );
    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
}
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
    $_POST['post_password'] = stripslashes($_POST['post_password']);

// Expires when the browser shuts down
setcookie( 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $wp_hasher->HashPassword( stripslashes( $_POST['post_password'] ) ), 0, COOKIEPATH );

wp_safe_redirect( get_bloginfo('url') . "/" . $_POST['event'] );
?>
```

Greets!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to hook that code so that it runs before any data is sent to the browser.

```
function remote_login_wpse_104911() {
  global $wp_hasher;
  if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php' );
    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
  }

  setcookie( 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $wp_hasher->HashPassword( stripslashes( $_POST['pw'] ) ), 0, COOKIEPATH );

  wp_safe_redirect( "http://www.domain.com/wordpress/".$_POST['name'] );
}
add_action('template_include','remote_login_wpse_104911');
```

That is completely untested. I don't have all the information I'd need to test it if I want to. :) You will almost certainly have to modify that to work in the new context. But that is the idea.

Comment: I didn't know template_include, this looks like an good idea! But if I try this, every page/subpage/post on my site will be redirected to $_POST['name']. As the login site is redirected too, I am redirected to the root (/wordpress/), even if I recheck if there was a form submitted. But actually there is no website showing up all in the browser ("Too much redirects").
  
But I understand the main idea to run this function remote_login_wpse_104911() before the specific page is loaded and so the access could be provided.

Comment: Actually, I forget about `template_include` also. I just copied your code into the function. You will have to modify it to work in the new context, of course.

Comment: I don't know where the error is. Even if I comment the redirect lines out, the page stays white.
Another possibility could be the indirect way via wp-login.php but I only know that the password must be delivered as $_POST['post_password']. If I could transfer POST variables without users action, actually only via PHP, this would be the solution, right?
So the visitor logs in, and my pp-redirect.php (or the function called by template_include) will redirect to wp-login delivering the password as a POST variable.