# How to get boolean if file A is attached to post B

Tags: attachments, links

I created a kind of customer area using several password-protected posts (for more details check this, but it's not necessary for this new issue: [Give visitor access to password protected page/post via external script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104911/give-visitor-access-to-password-protected-page-post-via-external-script))

On these posts there are several files attached via the plugin "Attachments" (http://wordpress.org/plugins/attachments/). Now, of course I want to prevent the capability to download the files via the direct access but just with the correct login data, so I googled and found this:
http://www.stephenharris.info/2012/restricting-direct-access-to-files-in-wordpress/

Short review so you don't have to read it completely:

1. the root .htaccess file is modified so everything (also files in /upload/) will be redirected to index.php
2. an action/function called "maybe_load_file" is added which checks whether the request is coming from the uploads folder and if so outputs the file.

My idea was to create a file like "download-redirect.php?id=x".
It checks if file with the id x exists, if the referrer is an event post, and if the password cookie is valid. Then it should check **if file with the id x is attached to event/post xyz**, if all of this is true a session variable with password hash and stuff would be set and the user would be redirected to the file path (see above). In my function "maybe_load_file" I would recheck if the referrer is download-redirect.php and if the session variable is set correctly and then output the files.

So this is my final question, sorry for my long introduction but I think it is necessary to understand the issue:
*How can I check if a file A is attached (via the plugin "attachments") to post B?*

Comment: Are you talking about a plugin called "attachments" or just regular post attachments?

Comment: I mean this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/attachments/

Answer (score 0):

Get all attachments:

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
) );
```

Check attachment "parent" for each attachment.

```
foreach($attachments as $attachment){
$parentID = $attachment->post_parent;
$postID = $post->ID;
if($parentID == $postID){
  //your code here
  echo 'This attachment belongs to the current post.';
  }
}
```

But if you already have the attachment, all you need is: 
note: By "have" i mean you previously queried it or saved it into a object previously.

```
$parentID = $attachment->post_parent;
$postID = $post->ID;
if($parentID == $postID){
  //your code here
  echo 'This attachment belongs to the current post.';
  }
```

Comment: But what if an attachment got multiple parents/multiple posts which use this attachment?